# Component Identification AHC373

Tags: identification, components

I'm trying to pin down this component

[image: AHC373 with nano SIM for scale]

Googling has got me to these two but I can't work out the difference or if they match.

[SN74AHC373DW](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/SN74AHC373DW?qs=sGAEpiMZZMu2QtOrmdJ1%2FZK%2F%252BZOdDBo6KrIeKBeRBq8%3D)

[SN74AHC373DWR](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/SN74AHC373DWR?qs=sGAEpiMZZMu2QtOrmdJ1%2FQmfMOZH7GgkTNF9w0mhQbI%3D)

Really appreciate some help IDing it. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Texas Instruments datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ahc373.pdf), the only difference between the two part numbers is how the chips are packaged:

[image]

The actual chips themselves are identical. They're both octal transparent D-type latches in a 20-SOIC package.

If you are hand-soldering or doing a small-batch, they are completely interchangeable.

If you are doing a large-scale assembly using automated equipment, you'll choose the -DWR part if your assembler/machine expects the parts on tape-and-reel and -DW if the machine expects to be fed from a tube.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to EE Stack Exchange!

You've pretty much done all the work already, thanks for that.

The part you have there is technically the [SN74AHC373](http://www.ti.com/product/SN74AHC373) from TI (see my username <3).

The "DW" and "DWR" are just there to designate the IC package and order quantity (DW in this case corresponds to SOIC, and the R means the large reel when ordering). From an electrical perspective the two part numbers you listed are identical.

You can see this info on the Order Now tab of TI's website.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!